# Recover deleted records from Snowflake if you don't remember the exact time / date

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to recover some records but I don't remember the exact time or date they were deleted:

I remember that these records that were deleted all had 'nan' values in `link` and `name` columns, and the `asof_date` values were between July & October.

I believe they were deleted 1 day ago so I tried this (since 1440 min in a day) but nothing populates:

```
select * from my_table at(offset => -60*1440) 
where link = 'nan'
and name = 'nan'
and to_date(asof_date) >= '2021-07-01'
and to_date(asof_date) <= '2021-10-13'
```

Comment: Did you tried with timestamp:
select * from my_table at(timestamp => 'Mon, 01 May 2015 16:20:00 -0700'::timestamp_tz);

Comment: First, check your DATA_RETENTION_TIME_IN_DAYS parameter value using the SHOW TABLES.
Because the default is 1 day and maybe you don't have the previous values anymore.

Comment: @MichaelGolos thank you I tried this: SHOW PARAMETERS like '%DATA_RETENTION_TIME_IN_DAYS%' in ACCOUNT ; and it shows 1. does that mean its gone forever and there's no way I can get it back?

Comment: @KristiLuna To be sure, check the "retention_time" parameter directly on the table using SHOW TABLES LIKE 'my_table'. If it is also 1 day, you still have 7 days of fail-safe protection. You need to quickly submit a support ticket so that they can get this table back at some point in time. For the future, it is worth changing this parameter at all tables and at the account level. Good luck!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, since your data retention period is only 1 day, you will not be able to make use of time travel or fail safe.

For future reference, provided that you have Enterprise edition or above, then you can set the retention period to be up to 90 days, and then you have 7 days fail-safe protection after that.

[Understanding & Using Time Travel](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-time-travel.html)